# Как выравнивать таблицы по центру в админке (Yii2)

Tags: bootstrap

Все никак не получается описание и краткое содержание уместить в один экран.
[image: Вид админки]

И где можно задать валидацию этим полям? Чтобы, к примеру, в столбце "Описание" выводился html без обработки ( к примеру, если выделен жирным шрифт, чтобы видно было так: < b >текст< / b > )